# What specifies the maximum supported sdcard capacity of a mobile phone?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, external-sd, sd-card, storage, hardware

I often see this in mobile phone specifications: "microsd card supported, up to 32gb"

1. Is this limit really real?
2. Does it depend on hardware or software?
3. How to know for sure (e.g. using a software) the limit?
4. What happens if inserted a card that exeeds the limit?